# Use the Using Statement to prevent open connection when working with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, using

Which is the correct way to use the `using` statement, to keep the connection to the database closed when not in use.

I have a constructor which sets my connection string, and sets up a new connection like this:

```
public MSSQL()
{
    string ConnectionString = "The address to database";
    connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
}
```

And then this is where I want to call the function that gets my data:

```
public async Task AddEmployee(Employee emp, string storedProcedureToAddEmployee = "AddEmployee")
{
    MSSQL rep = new MSSQL();
    using (rep.connection) { await connection.QueryAsync<Employee>(storedProcedureToAddEmployee, "Adding all info"}
}
```

And below is how I interpreted his solution (explained very vaguely)

```
public async Task AddEmployee(Employee emp, string storedProcedureToAddEmployee = "AddEmployee")
{            
    using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString")) 
    { 
        await con.QueryAsync<Employee>(storedProcedureToAddEmployee, "Adding all info"); 
    }
}
```

How do they differ, or is there something I've missed?

Comment: Just to point out: the Db driver in the background can and will handle the connections as it wants, so you closing a connection in the code no necessarily closes the real connection (most likely only the transaction)

Comment: The middle looks dangerous, since you're disposing of an object that you do not own.

Comment: ^ And the owner does not attempt to dispose it either. If you have a class that stores/is responsible for an `SqlConnection`, that class should implement `IDisposable` itself and you should be `using` that class, and the class should dispose the connection in its Dispose. You don't seem to need that class in the first place.

Comment: *Don't* store the connection in a field at all. The third option is really the only one. ADO.NET's connection pooling resets the connection and puts it in a pool of connections ready for reuse, so you gain *nothing* by caching the connection object. In fact, the cached connection will keep any locks acquired from previous queries, gradually leading to increased database conflicts and blocking

Comment: In the third case (which could be just `using (var con=new SqlConnection(..))`, any existing transactions will be rolled back and any acquired locks released when the connection is reset before it's placed back in the connection pool. Next time you want a connection you'll get an existing clean one from the pool

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. That helped me to understand!